# Django + Stripe: Webhooks

Tags: django, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using Stripe Connect for my Django application. After I read the Stripe documentation I still have few questions unanswered and I wonder if anyone knows the answer.

Case 1: Connected account refunds via Stripe Account

1. Webhook sends back > charge.refunded

Case 2: Connected account refunds via our platform

1. Platform sends refund call via API and new refund entry is added to refund model in the database
2. Webhook sends back > charge.refunded

I hope it's clear how I explained it. But in **both** cases I receive a webhook. That means I can't just add a new entry to the refund model every time I receive a webhook, as in Case 2 I already added this event to my database.

I now have two solutions in mind:

**1) I create a new 'log' model containing the event id. Before adding any data to my models, I check if this event was already logged.**

**2) I only work with the events coming via webhook. API calls lead to a Stripe event anyway, which I will receive via webhook. From there I can add the refund entry to my database.**

What solution did/would you choose?

Comment: What if you'll have some communication problem with Stripe service. Do you want refund will be recorded in your DB even if Stripe will not received refund call? In this case first method is OK. If you need to be fully synchronyzed with Stripe, I suppose second method is preferable.

Comment: Thank you! I just wrote with Stripe's support and solution 2) was recommended as well. I will additional log the events in an extra model, so even if webhooks are sent twice, I make sure I only process what's not already processed